# How to send release pipeline artifact (TestResults_runId.zip) by email in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, cypress, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-artifacts, test-results

I created a release pipeline in Azure DevOps to run my Cypress tests. Currently it hae the following tasks:

1. Use Node (Node.js tool installer)
2. Install Dependencies (nmp)
3. Run Tests (npm)
4. Publish Test Results (test result format JUnit)
5. Send Email (powershell script)

**my challange is** - how to send **TestResults_runId.zip** as an $Attachment using my pwershell script ?
[test results where number is generetated Id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZLGZ.png)

[my powershell script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uhjL.png)

Answer (score 1):

There are many Azure DevOps MarketPlace extension automate this, you can refer to [GitHub Send Email](https://github.com/renevanosnabrugge/SendEmail-BuildTask) and apply to your PowerShell script, or you can just install it and use it within your Task YAML.

Comment: thanks for your respond! I know how to send an email, but I'm still struggling with how to  send (attach) TestResults_123.zip in that email. thanks